# Multithread broadcasting in SignalR

Tags: signalr

I am using signalR in my application. Here is my use case

the data which needs to broadcast is generated by multiples threads. A single client can fall in multiple groups.

A thread can broadcast to mulitple groups. What will happen if more than one thread broadcasting at same time to a groups.

Do I have to take care of synchronisation while broadcasting the messages or is this taken care by SignalR ?

Answer (score 0):

`Same time` is rather difficult to achieve. (there will always be some difference between two events, so you don't have to worry about this).

Now, when you 2 pieces send data from `point A` to `point B`, depending on the technology used to send the data, even if the order in which you send is, let's say 1 and 2, it may happen that 2 arrives before 1 (just because the network isn't something you can control).

If the message order is important in your application, you should make the methods broadcasting to wait one another, so you should use asynchronous programming (by using the `async` and `await`.

To end, even if two different threads try to broadcast the same client at the same time, you don't have a problem, since the data from both threads will arrive at the client.  What you should take in consideration is the order in which this happens and if you need to preserve the message order.

Hope this helps. Best of luck!

EDIT: The reason you should not worry about 2 threads using the same `hub` is that whenever some class wants to call some users/groups of a `hub` by getting the `hub context`, since the `hub` instances are created per request.

[See this answer form the guy who created SignalR.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10262052/3084239)

Comment: Thanks  Matei_Radu , Order is not important for me as two threads publishing different type of data.  As far I know SignalR maintains buffer for each client. Do you mean this buffer is thread safe ?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, updated answer with link to relevant question. Best of luck!

Comment: This really helped but I am thinking in terms of transport that is next level of hub where websocket  is a single connection between server and client and how could two or more threads write at same time over the same connection without synchronization.